# Contar quantidades de um determinado atributo dentro de uma tabela

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

tudo bem?

Tenho a seguinte dúvida, criei um banco de dados para um jogo de cartas no estilo de Magic. Tenho uma tabela que mostra as habilidades e outra que mostra as cartas e, mais uma que chamei de carta_habilidade que mostra a carta e sua respectiva habilidade.

Eu gostaria de listar as habilidades e quantas cartas possuem uma determinada habilidade. Por exemplo a habilidade desaparecer apresenta 3 cartas que a têm. Abaixo está o código, mas dá o seguinte erro: "unknow column 'ch.idcarta' in 'where clause'

Como posso resolver esse problema? Agradeço pela ajuda.

```
select h.nome, count(h.nome)as quantidade
from carta_habilid
inner join habilidades h on ch.idhabilidades=h.idhabilidades
where ch.idcarta=c.idcarta 
group by h.nome;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas está faltando dizer à *query* quem é o `ch` que você quer referenciar:

```
from carta_habilid ch
inner join habilidades h on ch.idhabilidades=h.idhabilidades
where ch.idcarta=c.idcarta 
group by h.nome;
```